# Remove weird flicker when using Paging and Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-paging-3

Hello everybody,

Using the Android navigation component and Paging 3, I came across the following case:

The navigation component has a bottom navigation view and two fragments ListFragment (initial) and ProfileFragment, each fragment shows a list using Pager which shows the same values.  When you change fragments using the bottom navigation view, no flickering occurs (unless it is the first time we enter the ProfileFragment that is not the initial one).

However, if in ListFragment we update some elements of the list and navigate to the ProfileFragment, a flicker occurs. On the other hand, if we update an element in ProfileFragment and navigate back to the ListFragment, this fliker does not happen. I understand it's because, by default in the Android navigation component, it doesn't destroy the initial fragment.

This flicker is not a desired behaviour and I would appreciate any help, also in this repo, you will find a minimal reproduction of this case https://github.com/RafaelAmoMoralDev/PagingQuestion. If you have some doubts,  don't hesitate to ask me and I will answer as soon as possible.